# cannot import dmatrices from patsy

Tags: python, patsy

I'm trying to use `dmatrices()` function from `patsy` package in pycharm, but I get following error when impoting:

`from patsy import dmatrices`

Cannot find reference 'dmatrices' in '**init**.py'

my python version is 3.8

Answer (score 2):

I know this is SUPER old at this point but `from patsy.highlevel import dmatrices` actually solved the issue for me. I just ran into this exact issue